# SRAM compatible 11 speed 12-25 cassette?

Tags: gears, cassette, drivetrain, sram

I'm looking for an 11 speed 12-25 cassette compatible with a SRAM drivetrain, however I don't think SRAM makes one.

They list specs for their 11 speed cassettes as follows:

```
11-25: 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,21,23,25 
11-26: 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,21,23,26 
11-28: 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,22,25,28
11-30: 11,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,24,27,30 
11-32: 11,12,13,14,15,17,19,22,25,28,32
```

Are there any manufacturers that make a 12-25 that is compatible with SRAM? I'd also be interested in a 12-** cassette as long as it has an 18 tooth cog.

Comment: Try a Shimano cassette. They are compatible and there's a 12-25 Ultegra CS-6800 that has an 18 tooth cog.

Comment: @Carel Really...the indexing and spacing is close enough to work?

Comment: Why do you want a 12-** ? It's got less range than an 11-**.

Comment: @BSOrider closer ratios. You loose the 11 but gain an 18. How often are you pushing a 53/11?

Comment: Not very often :) Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read Zinn's articles ([a](http://velonews.competitor.com/2015/03/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-10-11-speed-drivetrain-component-compatibility_362722), [b](http://velonews.competitor.com/2014/07/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-1011-speed-compatibility_337803), [c](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/09/bikes-and-tech/drivetrain-compatibility-hidden-in-plain-sight_303199), probably others) on 11 speed drivetrain compatibility.

The surprising upshot is this: You can swap a Campagnolo 11 speed, Shimano 11 speed and SRAM 11 speed wheel in for each other and they will work (*). You can put SRAM and Shimano cassettes on each other's freehub bodies.

The Shimano Ultegra CS-6800 comes in a 12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-21-23-25, so this is a cassette you can buy and use.

(*) Zinn notes there might be a tiny amount of indexing adjustment necessary. The SRAM/Shimano swap for wheels isn't really surprising, but the Campagnolo one is.

Answer (score 0):

The 11-25 will work fine with the SRAM components, the bigger question is whether your derailleur will handle the change in cassette range. Head to your local shop for specifics. It probably will, but that's the part you should go about verifying.

Comment: I'm already running an 11-25, I'm looking for a 12-25.  SRAM doesn't make one (that I can find).

Comment: @ebrohman: Not only do SRAM not make a 12-25 cassette, they don't even make an 18t cog.  So creating your own cassette from SRAM bits is not practical either.

Answer (score -1):

Shimano cassettes will work with Sram 11 speed, but it will be noisy. Based on experiences and frustration.

Comment: This answer is a bit short, and mostly duplicates existing answers.  You would be better to add the bit about noise to another answer, with a comment.  Adding comments requires some more reputation points, so answer a few more questions to earn rep.